# hook_block_view For an Array of Paragraphs

Tags: hooks

Is there a way to use the theme() function to process an array of paragraphs, in a fashion to how theme('item_list', $theme_args) works?

If there is not a way using the theme function, what then is the "preferred" way to create a render array for an array of paragraphs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a 'preferred' way, or built in function, to render an array of paragraphs. You could do it like this:

```
$build = array(
  'p1' => array(
    '#markup' => 'Something',
    '#prefix' => '<p>',
    '#suffix' => '</p>',
  ),
  'p2' => array(
    '#markup' => 'Something else',
    '#prefix' => '<p>',
    '#suffix' => '</p>',
  ),
);
```

Or this:

```
$build = array(
  'p1' => array(
    '#markup' => '<p>Something</p>',
  ),
  'p2' => array(
    '#markup' => '<p>Something else</p>',
  ),
);
```

Or you could build a theme function which takes an array of paragraphs and builds up an HTML string. Or you could use some variation of `implode()`, or a simple loop, and so on.

It really depends on how you want to approach it, there are several equally valid ways to solve that problem.